# redirect back to currently open .net maui app?

Tags: authentication, maui

I am attempting to Login to my company's custom authentication service. I do not have access to anything but the client app that I've built with .NetMaui. The URL they have given me is

- [companyurl]/Account/Login,

I also have a much larger url that theyve used in the past:

- [companyurl]/login.aspx?WL_Type=I&WL_AppId=iswitch&WL_ReturnMethod=FV&WL_Expire=1&ReturnMethod=Get&WL_ReturnUrl=[AppUrl].Maui/Pages/LoginPage.xaml?p1=v1"

I have attempted both of these with OpenBrowserAsync[1] and using WinUIEx[1]

1. OpenBrowser, when the redirect occurs, opens a new instance of the app, which is not what is wanted.
2. WinUiEx doesnt redirect me at all.

I have registerd the app schema, hence why it is able to open a new instance of the app

Please help, bros. What can I do?

Comment: What you want is to jump from the MAUI program to the company's custom authentication service website via a URL, right?

Comment: I am opening the browser from the app, and I would like to redirect back to the currently open app

Comment: could you post minimum code and clarify ? how the new instance of the app is launched from the browser currently still unclear to me.

Comment: Why not put the website in the Maui program's Webview so that you don't have to jump between the browser and the application?